# Alternatives to Elastic Beanstalk in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using currently Elastic Beanstalk to deploy and run an executable jar (Spring Boot app). I'm using a t2.small ec2 instance (2Go) which is sufficient for my need and for the size of the application.

I'm encountring now several problems :

1. Deploying new version of the app is tooooo slow. I have to wait more than 10 minutes to changes take effects.
2. 60% of the time, the deployment does not work. A rollback is done by EB which takes another 5 or 10 minutes.
3. Nothing is reported to log files. So I have no idea why deployment does not work.

Below example of errors I get.

---

```
2018-05-04 16:45:25 UTC+0200    INFO    requestEnvironmentInfo is starting.
2018-05-04 16:45:09 UTC+0200    INFO    Pulled logs for environment instances.
2018-05-04 16:45:09 UTC+0200    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, TimedOut: 1].
2018-05-04 16:45:09 UTC+0200    WARN    The following instances have not responded in the allowed command timeout time (they might still finish eventually on their own): [i-04cb070a376fbf077].
2018-05-04 16:31:06 UTC+0200    INFO    requestEnvironmentInfo is starting.
2018-05-04 16:12:10 UTC+0200    WARN    Environment health has transitioned from Info to Degraded. Incorrect application version found on all instances. Expected version "deepan-core-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT" (deployment 10). Application update is aborting (running for 15 minutes).
2018-05-04 16:11:33 UTC+0200    ERROR   During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.
2018-05-04 16:11:33 UTC+0200    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.
2018-05-04 16:11:33 UTC+0200    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-04cb070a376fbf077'. Aborting the operation.
```

### Is there any reliable alternatives I can use on AWS to deploy a Spring Boot executable jar ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: For what purpose? you need load balancing etc.,? If not, just rent EC2 instance and SSH then move code and run. You can automate some of these things based on how big your setup is.

Comment: I want to start with a simple application. It run actually under a load balancer just to redirect http to https and to add the ssl certificate.

Comment: May be ELB + EC2 could be an interesting alternative.

Comment: ELB ? What's ELB ?

Comment: ELB stands for elastic load balancer

Answer (score 0):

Without more information I'll have to guess, maybe during deployment your T instance ran out of credits and stopped responding, try using a "M" instance (you can save money by running on m6g - ARM64) and see if it improve your deployment experience. Also part of the slow deployment could be due to the low mem/cpu of your EC2 instance. Check cloudWatch metrics and make sure you did not run out of credits and that the machine CPU is not at peak usage most of the time.

Three alternatives that you can consider:

1. is either using [AWS AppRunner](https://aws.amazon.com/apprunner/) pass the code and define your environment, but more expensive.
2. If you have more than one website or plan on running multiple instances consider using containers (using ECS/EKS) on a bigger EC2 instance, you would have the ability to run multiple websites isolated from one another on the same infrastructure (EC2 + EBS).
3. 3. If you're willing to make code changes, perhaps it would be simpler to run on AWS Lambda, with API Gateway for small workloads it could be more cost efficient

Other than that if you only plan to run on small instance then the alternative is to use self managed EC2 instance but then you will need to manage the deployments as well.